# Typescript sequence of a Class methods

Tags: javascript, class, methods, callback, typescript

I got a typescript class with an attribute that contain some connection data that are the result of an ajax call, here's a snippet:

```
class User {
    // ... other stuff (constructor, attributes, methods)
    static data:{id:number; token:string} = {id: 0, token: ""};
    connect() {
        // Ajax Call
        .done(function(e){
            User.data.id = e.id;
            User.data.token = e.token;
        })
    }
    request() {
        if(User.data.id == 0)
            setTimeout(() => { 
                this.request();
            }, 500);
        else return  '?id=' + User.data.id + '&token=' + User.data.token;
    }
}
```

I tried to use `connect()` and subsequently `request()` but sometimes the request() function starts before ajax's answer. Now I'm trying to write the `request()` function with some waiting time and a sort of recursion. Unfortunately it doesn't work.. My goal is to call the `request()` function and obtain the string only when "id" and "token" are ready (not 0 and empty string). Any suggestion would be appreciated!

PS: I can't put the `request()` function inside the ajax callback: the two functions should be separated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calling code should be combining the promises with `then`. `connect()` and `request()` should just return their promises. e.g.  they "promise to return done when connected" and "promise to return the requested data". In the case of `request`, it does not need a `deferred` object or promise as it simply returns a value immediately.

JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/qcjrLv4k/3/

```
// Return a fake connection after 5 seconds
var connect = function (){
    var def = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function(){
        def.resolve();
    }, 5000);
    return def.promise();
}

var request = function(){
    return "?data=d";
}
```

and use like this:

```
connect().then(request).done(function(data){
    alert(data);
});
```

So in your case, just return the ajax call result as a promise from `connect()`:

```
   connect() {
        return $.ajax({[snipped]})
        .done(function(e){
            User.data.id = e.id;
            User.data.token = e.token;
        });
    }
```

and `request` simply returns the string:

```
request() {
    return '?id=' + User.data.id + '&token=' + User.data.token;
}
```

Another way to do it is to save the `connect` promise:

```
var promise = connect();
```

and use it whenever you want to get the `request` data:

```
promise.then(request).done(function(data){
    alert(data);
});
```

**A better way**, if your `request` is dependent on a "connection", is to pass the `connect` promise to the `request` method as a required parameter:

```
request(connectionPromise){
    return connectionPromise.then(function(){
         return '?id=' + User.data.id + '&token=' + User.data.token;
    });
};
```

and call with:

```
request(connect()).done(function(data){
   alert(data);
});
```

Example using this approach here: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/qcjrLv4k/4/

**Final example** (based on commented desire to reuse connection). Combine the previous answers like this:

1) Save the connection as a property of the object.

```
// Start the connection process and save the promise for re-use
var connectionPromise = connect();
```

2) Use the connection as a parameter to the requests (so they do not need to have knowledge of the external variable):

```
// Make a request, passing the connection promise
request(connectionPromise).done(function(data){
   alert(data);
});
```

3) The request method does not change from the previous example:

```
request(connectionPromise){
    return connectionPromise.then(function(){
         return '?id=' + User.data.id + '&token=' + User.data.token;
    });
};
```

Comment: Tnx for your answer, I'm going to study in deep these arguments. In your code every request try and wait for a connection to be solved but this isn't good for me cause in my code I need the possibility to make several "request()" with just one initial connection and the problem is just with the first request (cause sometimes connection data are not ready for it).

Comment: @Plastic: I will add an extra options specifically based on your desire to reuse the connection.

Comment: Thank you so much, my first goal here is to learn something useful ;)

Answer (score 0):

Once you are in promise land you need to stay there (or use a callback):

```
class User {
    // ... other stuff (constructor, attributes, methods)
    static data: { id: number; token: string } = { id: 0, token: "" };

    private connectedPromise;
    connect() {
        // Ajax Call
        this.connectedPromise = something.done( function ( e ) {
            User.data.id = e.id;
            User.data.token = e.token;
        })
    }
    request() {
        this.connectedPromise.then( () => {
            if ( User.data.id == 0 )
                setTimeout( () => {
                    this.request();
                }, 500 );
            else return '?id=' + User.data.id + '&token=' + User.data.token;
        })
    }
}
```

Store the result of connect in a var on only execute request if connect has resolved.

**PS** the request function is bad (I haven't cleaned it up but removed the return) in that it is *maybe* async i.e. it either returns a value or does some async work. Better to be consistent and *always* be async.

Comment: you said i need to stay with promise or use a callback.. Witch approach is better?

Comment: @basarat: Promises should be chained, not be stitched together by adding dependencies (in your case the `connectedPromise` variable). Have added an example.

Comment: Also the `setTimeout` code was only required as there were no promises (it was simply polling recursively for the connection to complete). You only need `return '?id=' + User.data.id + '&token=' + User.data.token`.

Comment: Like I said. I didn't cleanup :)